# VS suggests to override a shadowing function, but refuses to accept the Overrides declaration. How do I fix this?

Tags: vb.net, interface, overriding

In my `Windows Forms Control Library` project is a user control and a class used by said user control.

The user control, as for my understanding, has nothing to do with my problem. Just for sake of completeness: it inherits from `UserControl`, as documented in the `Designer.vb`:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class UFB
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
    ...
End Class
```

The class is the part in which I have problems. In it, I want to implement the `IEquatable` interface:

```
Public Class CPT
    Implements IEquatable(Of CPT)

    ...

    Public Function Equals(oOther As CPT) As Boolean _
        Implements IEquatable(Of CPT).Equals

        ...
    End Function
End Class
```

However, VS complains that the function 'Equals' shadows an overridable method in the base class 'Object'. To override the base method, this method must be declared 'Overrides'.

"Fine", I said, "there we go":

```
    Public Overrides Function Equals(oOther As CPT) As Boolean _
        Implements IEquatable(Of CPT).Equals

        ...
    End Function
```

But now VS complains, that the function 'Equals' cannot be declared 'Overrides', because it does not override a function in a base class.

So, what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Overloads` keyword:

```
Public Class CPT
    Implements IEquatable(Of CPT)

    ...

    Public Overloads Function Equals(oOther As CPT) As Boolean _
        Implements IEquatable(Of CPT).Equals

        ...
    End Function
End Class
```

That keyword is not required when both overloads are declared in the same type but when you overload a method declared in a base type, you need to be explicit.  Now you have two `Equals` methods with different signatures, which is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I moved over from C# to VB.NET development, and those apparently contradictory messages were mystifying to me. +1.